# What is the difference between docker run -p and ports in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to use a standard way of running my docker containers. I have have been keeping a `docker_run.sh` file, but docker-compose.yml looks like a better choice. This seems to work great until I try to access my website running in the container. The ports don't seem to be set up correctly.

Using the following `docker_run.sh`, I can access the website at `localhost`. I expected the following `docker-compose.yml` file to have the same results when I use the `docker-compose run web` command.

### docker_run.sh

```sh
docker build -t web .
docker run -it -v /home/<user>/git/www:/var/www -p 80:80/tcp -p 443:443/tcp -p 3316:3306/tcp web
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: web
        build: .
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "3316:3306"
        volumes:
            - "../www:/var/www"
```

## Further analysis

The ports are reported as the same in `docker ps` and `docker-compose ps`. Note: these were not up at the same time.

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                              NAMES
<id>        web      "/usr/local/scripts/…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   <name>
```

```sh
$ docker-compose ps
Name            Command               State                                Ports                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
web   /usr/local/scripts/start_s ...   Up      0.0.0.0:3316->3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: `ports` in `docker-compose.yml` and `-p` in `docker run` are the same.  They map published ports.  I think what you should be trying to do is `docker-compose up` instead of `docker-compose run`

Comment: @richyen `docker-compose up` does expose the ports as I want, however I have to include `tty: true` in docker-compose.yml` to keep the container running. Adding the `--service-ports` to `docker-compose run` does what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @richyen suggests in a comment, you want `docker-compose up` instead of `docker-compose run`.

[`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)...

> Runs a one-time command against a service.

That is, it's intended to run something like a debugging shell or a migration script, in the overall environment specified by the `docker-compose.yml` file, but not the standard command specified in the Dockerfile (or the override in the YAML file).

Critically to your question,

> ...`docker-compose run` [...] does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports. If you do want the service’s ports to be created and mapped to the host, specify the `--service-ports` flag.

Beyond that, the `docker run` command you show and the `docker-compose.yml` file should be essentially equivalent.

Comment: The `--service-ports` flag is what I was missing. Thank you. This command is now gives the results I want: `docker-compose run --service-ports web`

Answer (score 0):

You don't run docker-compose.yamls the same way that you would run a local docker image that you have either installed or created on your machine. docker-compose files are typically launched running the command `docker-compose up -d` to run in detached mode. Then when you run `docker ps` you should see it running. You can also run `docker-compose ps` as you did above.

Comment: I am beginning to understand that I'm trying to use docker-compose in an nontraditional way. It still seems better than including a `docker_run.sh` script because I am only using Docker for local development at this point.